# method call from Akka actor receive method is not handling passed message

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In the below simplified code snippet, if functionality of receive is refactored out, then it don't handle incoming messages as expected.

```
package spack

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging

object Main extends LazyLogging {

  import logger._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    debug("start of main")

    val system = ActorSystem("SampleSystem")

    val ref = system.actorOf(Props[SampleActor])

    ref ! "Hello"

    debug("end of main")

    Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
  }
}

class SampleActor extends Actor with LazyLogging {

  import logger._


  override def receive: Receive = {


    case msg => {
      debug("now calling handle")
      handleMsg(msg)
    }


  }

  def handleMsg(msg1: Any): Receive = {
    case msg1 => debug(s"received msg is $msg1")
  }
}
```

Output of above  code snippet :-

```
22:06:17.889 [main] DEBUG spack.Main$ - start of main
22:06:18.569 [main] DEBUG spack.Main$ - end of main
22:06:18.569 [SampleSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] DEBUG spack.SampleActor - now calling handle
```

I was expecting below line also in the output, but somehow, it's not coming.

> received msg is "Hello"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem:

`handleMsg` returns a Partial function called `Receive` but does not evaluate it. Thats why no output is shown

1. Use `context.become` to the behavior of the actor

or

2. Make `handleMsg` function return Unit, instead of unevaluated Partial function

Define your `handleMsg` like below

```
def handleMsg(arg: Any): Unit = arg match {
  case msg => debug(s"received msg is $msg")
}
```

Or

```
def handleMsg: Receive = {
    case msg1 => debug(s"received msg is $msg1")
  }
```

## You can use become

```
case msg => {
  debug("now calling handle")
  context become handleMsg
  self ! msg
}
```